# Freeze-of-windows-7-x64-on-laptop by Chromium - Xperf log

Tags: windows-7, freeze, chromium

Lpatop spec - AMD Lllano A6 3400M, Gpu 6520G and 6650M, 2x2GB Ram, Atheros AR9002WB-1NG Wireless Network Adapter, Hitachi HTS725032A9A364.

Security software Microsoft Security Essential on Windows 7x64 SP1, .Net framework 4.5

Desktop freeze Issue is long time problem on this machine ranging from IE 10, Chromium, FF. The freezes are once per boot basis Usually 5 to 20 sec in duration with a intense disk activity and recover afterwards without any event log entry.

I tried updating .NET framework and wireless driver and disabling NIC but the issue reappears after few days. The issue is reproducible by visiting particular sites like toms-hardware, the-verge, Life-hacker etc (flash version 11.8.800)

**Performance tookit log** itself (dropbox) http://db.tt/cbspiLWB
during such a lock up visiting the-next-web
whooops 10 rep limit can't post screenshots

a butt load of disk activity in ***C:\Windows\System32\catroot\xxxxxxxxx.cat***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with the Audiodg.exe which can cause such freezes. When the service is started the first time Windows scans all CAT files from `C:\Windows\System32\catroot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\`.

I've already reported this to Microsoft, but I have no idea if it is fixed in Windows 8, because the issue only occurs if you have a large number of MUI packs or a lot of updates installed.

Comment: I will try to boot with disabling audio device and service, The said folder is ~58mb and 2069 items,  The same issue http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162028

Comment: this is a Windows issue which can't be fixed by 3rd parties. So the bug tracker entry is useless.

Comment: I tried disabling both (High Definition Audio Device)(AMD High Definition Audio Device) and reboot no 'audiodg.exe' still the issue persist. Other thing i tried updating catalyst if thats relevant but no

Comment: Issue is solved after Microsoft released WU Cleanup tool via Disk Cleanup

Comment: yes, this removes a lot of old update which causes Windows to scan less CAT files.